# Can an language invented before a challenge was posted be used to answer the challenge if it lacked an interpreter at the time?

Tags: discussion

Say I invent a language, post a list of commands and general structure on GitHub, and then begin working on the interpreter.  After finishing the interpreter, could I use this language to answer challenges posted before the interpreter was completed?

Comment: Your answer: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11688/42545 TL;DR: no. The *interpreter* has to exist, not the *spec*.

Comment: Thank-you, for some reason I couldn't find that, but I was pretty sure something of the type had to exist somewhere.