# What to count in assembly?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, answers, scoring

Yes, I've checked [this post (How are bytes counted in assembly)](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12339/how-are-bytes-counted-in-assembly/), but I'm asking a different question. I'm asking, if I have an `.asm` file, an `.obj` file and an `.exe` file, which one should I submit? Which **part** in the code should I submit? Especially for `.obj` files and `.exe` files -- I have no idea which part of code is the real assembled code, while others are only boilerplates.

Comment: If you read the linked post, then it should be clear that object files are not assembly at all. If you're asking how to golf in machine code, then... I don't know a damn thing, so feel free to edit your question to ask that (or head over to [the chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119011/code-golf-machine-coders)).

Comment: If you submit `.asm` (whether it is a function or a program), then it simply becomes a valid assembly submission. I think a full program machine code submission should be the entirety of the `.exe` or whatever executable you have, but for a function submission, I believe most machine code golfers use some kind of disassembly tool (which shows the address, the raw machine code bytes in hex, and the corresponding assembly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's up to you!

Some of my assembly answers are provided as instruction listings, because the assembly IR / target code is larger than the mnemonic size.

For x86, it's usually the best idea to provide the assembled machine code as a flat binary, state where the entry point is, and describe the calling convention. If you need to access the system interface, **you're locked out of libc**, so you'll have to use either linux syscalls, or whatever your operating system supports.

You can also post DOS .com submissions - MS-DOS provides you some system API's (and some users on codegolf made a lot of MS-DOS specific answers!), but also it provides you the flexibility and code golf potential with unrestricted hardware and memory access.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Actually I only have MASM available, no Linux :) Is "disassemble and find the expected part" a good option?

Comment: I advise you to use nasm, which has the binary output format, making stuff much more convenient.

Comment: Here's the link: [nasm](https://nasm.us/) Also, ndisasm makes disassembly very convenient (MASM doesn't come with this tool).