# Judging the score of physically constructed electronic logic

Tags: discussion, scoring

How would physically constructed logic be scored? Say, for example, a mixture of resistors, diodes, wires, and 74xx/4000 type ICs.

Handmade logic fits the "programming language" criteria, as using only the above listed components, a Brainfuck interpreter could be constructed. However, there is no way to score it, which makes it impossible to use on PPCG until a scoring mechanism is decided.

Proposals will be taken in the "Answers" section of this post.

Answer (score 2):

### [Languages are defined by their implementations](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/48198)

*Handmade logic* doesn't have an implementation per se, you need to specify one (eg. Verilog or another HDL) and count the bytes of the `.v` file (in case of Verilog).

If you can't find an implementation that supports the components you want to use or you're unhappy with the found one(s) (eg. because they're ungolfy) nobody will hinder you from implementing your own Golf-HDL.