# Can I use here my own language for code-golfing?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, languages

Can I golf in my own programming language here?
I ask it 'cause there is no online way to check it out.

Comment: It's best practice to link to an implementation or an esolangs page in the answer. You can even ask Dennis to add the language to TIO if it isn't too trivial, but he hasn't responded to messages in a while

Comment: Also, it is generally required that your language, especially the features you use in an answer, predate the question. Otherwise you could implement a one-character solution for just about any question on the site and win every challenge.

Comment: If you were serious about it, you'd do a zero-character solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, but an interpreter or compiler is required

Languages on this site are [defined by their implementation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/36398). This means that there has to be an interpreter/compiler (online or offline) in which programs can be run.

Obviously, it is most convenient if the program can be run online (such as in [Try It Online](https://tio.run/#)), but it is perfectly acceptable if the interpreter/compiler has to be installed offline. The key is that people should be able to verify that the answer is valid.

Answer (score 8):

## Yes

It is quite common for participants here to use their own languages, and indeed, some of the languages used here (e.g. NARS2000 and TI-Basic) cannot be tried online.

Answer (score 3):

## Most Certainly Yes

Some examples of users using their own programming language:

- [Me, using Keg](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/196826/78850)
- [@a'_', using W](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/194982/78850)
- [@Adnan, using 05AB1E](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/181844/78850)
- [@Dennis, using Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/190861/78850)
- [@BusinessCat, using Gaia](https://github.com/splcurran/Gaia)
- [@Mego, using Actually/Seriously](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously)
- [@ASCII-Only, using Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal)
- [@sporeball, using naz](https://github.com/sporeball/naz)
- [@isaacg, using Pyth](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/53818/78850)

Comment: Feel free to add anymore examples.

Comment: This can be applied to [everyone on this list](https://github.com/ETHproductions/), except, for a matter of fact, GolfScript's creator.

Comment: I think [this](https://github.com/ETHproductions/golfing-langs) is the link @a'_' intended