# Quine in Pxem, a language whose program is represented as a pair of strings. Is outputting the filename a quine?

Tags: discussion, quine

[My quine in Pxem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/221399#221399) was [criticised as not being a quine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/69/golf-you-a-quine-for-great-good/221399#comment523281_221399), as they output their filenames, not the content of those files. A [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem) program is represented as a pair of a filename and content of file.

So far I have submitted three versions of quines; one requires content of file to be empty; the other two do not. Are these valid quines per our site rules?

Should I consider resubmitting as distinct notation such as [esolang-box](https://github.com/hakatashi/esolang-box#pxem) who represents a Pxem program as a string?

Comment: I think my solution would be to invent a language "Pxem2", which is basically Pxem but where the program until the first null byte is interpreted as the file name, so that you don't have any of these issues

Comment: @pxeger Then it's enough in esolang-box; it uses first LF instead of null as a separator.

Comment: I've edited your question a bit to format it more as a "question" rather that a list of bullet points. Additionally, I've modified your links to link to the answer itself, along with the comments discussing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quines are defined as

> A quine is a computer program which takes no input and produces a copy of its own **source code** as its only output.
>
> <sub>Emphasis mine. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)). Also [cited](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69/66833) in the original question</sub>

Despite Pxem's unusual execution manner, filenames are not source code. Therefore, a valid submission to the quine challenge should be a program which accepts no input, and outputs the exact code in the file, regardless of the filename. Anything else is not a valid quine.

Additionally:

> Also, in many languages, an empty file is also a quine: that isn't considered a legit quine either.

Meaning that at least one of your submissions is invalid.

If there is an interpreter, such as esolang-box where you can submit it as a single file which outputs its source code, this is valid per our rules that [a language is defined by its implementation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/66833). esolang-box says:

> Pxem
>
> The first line is the file name of the pxem code.
>
> The rest is the content of the pxem code.

So, while being slightly "edge-case"-y, if a program like

```
file.pxem
output
this text
```

outputs

```
file.pxem
output
this text
```

when run on esolang-box, I'd consider this to be an acceptable quine.