# Esoteric programming languages

Tags: support, languages

Are there any restrictions on what programming languages you can use in a challenge, and if you created your own programming language and you wanted to submit it to a code challenge, does there need to be a working interpreter which actually executes the code or can there just be some set out syntax but no program which interprets the language? Thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked a bunch of times before - the post it was just marked as a duplicate of should provide a good starting point as to what counts as a 'language'. It's a decent question though. If you have any more questions about whether or not something counts as appropriate, feel free to join [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte) and ask.

Comment: Additionally, because the linked question doesn't exactly make it fully clear: yes, you do need to provide a working interpreter, as languages here are [defined by their implementation](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7833/66833), *not* their specification

Comment: Okay. Then I will try to code an interpreter for my language.